# database table design with datetime

Tags: database-design

I want to store events in table with datetime and need to return the events count based on user request like hourly, daily, monthly etc.

so i am thinking of two designs

tbEvents

eventDate datetime, eventId   int

tbEvents

year int, month int, day int, hour int, eventId int

Since I want to groupBy like (year)/(year, month)/(year, month, day) in different queries, I want a optimum table design. Please help me to choose.

Comment: What database are you going to be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a single datetime entry is almost certainly the right choice (unless you are on some obscure db)

you cn always parse that with built in sql functions at query time.

Comment: Thanks. I will be using datepart() in group by. So I thought it will be performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below queries

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbEvents where convert(varchar(4), [eventDate], 111) ='2011'  --Year
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbEvents where convert(varchar(7), [eventDate], 111) ='2011/07' --Year/Month
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbEvents where convert(varchar, [eventDate], 111) ='2011/07/24'  --Year/Month/Date
```

Check with this URL [How to format datetime & date in Sql Server 2005](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/), Nice post about Datetime

Example GROUP BY Years

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  proc_YearEvents
AS
Begin
CREATE TABLE #EVENT (E_year varchar(4),E_month varchar(7),E_date varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #EVENT (E_year,E_month,E_date) 
SELECT convert(varchar(4), [eventDate], 111) E_year, convert(varchar(7), [eventDate], 111) E_month,convert(varchar(10), [eventDate], 111) E_date FROM [tbEvents]
SELECT E_Year,COUNT(*) from #EVENT GROUP BY E_year
END

EXEC proc_Events
```